# The price of product variations is not updated in the views

Tags: views, 8, commerce

I created a view page to display the catalog of my products.
Some products or variations.
When I change the variation in the view, the price does not change.

What have I done wrong?

[image]

You can test with the link and use the following login :

https://www.s1biose.com/test-2

**user :** test

**password :** test

There are two variations with different prices. But it does not change.

[image]

```
uuid: a939e1a9-ae08-4288-a47e-97cf5efb2463
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.commerce_product.variations
  module:
    - commerce_price
    - commerce_product
id: test_2
label: 'test 2'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: commerce_product_field_data
base_field: product_id
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: none
        options: {  }
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: none
        options:
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: default
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        sku:
          id: sku
          table: commerce_product_variation_field_data
          field: sku
          relationship: variations
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: false
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: true
          entity_type: commerce_product_variation
          entity_field: sku
          plugin_id: field
        price__number:
          id: price__number
          table: commerce_product_variation_field_data
          field: price__number
          relationship: variations
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: number
          type: commerce_price_calculated
          settings:
            strip_trailing_zeroes: false
            display_currency_code: false
          group_column: ''
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: true
          entity_type: commerce_product_variation
          entity_field: price
          plugin_id: field
        variations:
          id: variations
          table: commerce_product__variations
          field: variations
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: commerce_add_to_cart
          settings:
            combine: false
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: true
          plugin_id: field
      filters:
        product_id:
          id: product_id
          table: commerce_product_field_data
          field: product_id
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: '='
          value:
            min: ''
            max: ''
            value: '12'
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          entity_type: commerce_product
          entity_field: product_id
          plugin_id: numeric
      sorts: {  }
      title: 'test 2'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships:
        variations:
          id: variations
          table: commerce_product__variations
          field: variations
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: 'variations : Variation du produit'
          required: false
          plugin_id: standard
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
      use_ajax: true
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.commerce_product.variations'
  page_1:
    display_plugin: page
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders:
        metatag_display_extender: {  }
      path: test-2
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.commerce_product.variations'
```

Comment: Did you clear the site (render) cache? Administration > performance > Clear cache. Also be aware that Drupal commerce was still in beta some days ago, so it might still contain bugs.

Comment: @Neograph734 I have the update but it still does not work, you can test on https://www.s1biose.com/produit "user : test","password : test"

Comment: I am sorry, my French is not that good, but I don't think there are any product variations to see there. (Could you upload a views screenshot in english? It could increase your chances of an answer.)

Comment: @Neograph734 I have updated my question

Comment: Much better. Have you already tried to display 'rendered entities' inside your view? Either as a format, or as a field. Perhaps Commerce does some magic with an entity that does not apply if you render individual fields. If that works, you can create additional display modes in the administration area, in which you can add the fields you need. Make sure you add such a display mode for your product and that it at least includes the price and add to cart field (and other dynamic properties you might have).

Comment: @Neograph734 The "rendered entity" display works but I have many different views in several views. So I want to keep the "fields" view. When I do "entity rendered" on the "product variation" field it does not display the form.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas, sorry... Perhaps someone else comes along with a good idea. Good luck!

Comment: Someone would have a solution? I'm desperate with the "Commerce 2"

Comment: Who can do a test on smplytest.me and confirm that it does not work ?